# Skipping goalseek calculation when goal = 0

Tags: vba, excel

I have made a goalseek function that runs through several columns and automatically does calculation, even when the value selected in the goal field is equal to 0.

I want the sub to skip calculations whenever there is a "0" in my sheet and go to the next column.

Tried to add `If cell.Value > 0 And cell.Value <= cell.Offset(-1).Value Then _`, but it didn't work. It just inserted 0's in all the cells.

Here's my code:

```
Sub Goalseek()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("pb_input").Range("BB62:BP62")
        rng.Offset(1).Value = 0
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If cell.Value <= cell.Offset(-1).Value Then _
        cell.Offset(2) = 1 Else _
        cell.Offset(2) = -1
        cell.Goalseek Goal:=cell.Offset(-1).Value, ChangingCell:=cell.Offset(1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you show your IF statement exactly as it was placed in the module? Your approach seems correct so could be a syntax thing.

Comment: Also just a note you shouldn't use _ like that; far less confusing to create separate lines and use END IF. My gut says a similar problem for your other If statement caused the error.

Comment: Hi @Grade'Eh'Bacon. I'm not sure what you mean by your question. I ran the code in the module as I always do. The cells that depend on row 63 and 64 are all zero.

Comment: Outer loop failed: Sub Goalseek()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Selection

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("pb_input").Range("BB62:BP62")

    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If cell.Value <> 0 Then
        rng.Offset(1).Value = 0
            For Each cell In rng.Cells
                If cell.Value <= cell.Offset(-1).Value Then _
                    cell.Offset(2) = 1 Else _
                    cell.Offset(2) = -1
                    cell.Goalseek Goal:=cell.Offset(-1).Value, ChangingCell:=cell.Offset(1)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Comment: Edit your question, instead of adding code to comments, please (hard to read). And what I mean by the question is - you have an IF statement above that you say you tried to insert, but we can't see how you tried to insert it. And you will be greatly served by avoiding the _ connection of the IF THEN ELSE statements; that is less clear than taking the time to write separate lines, all indented, ending with an END IF.

Answer (score 0):

It's your coding style that's causing the problem. If you put an `If` statement on the one line (and your underscore character means this), then only the conditional statements in that line will comprise your `If` clause.

So in your code,

```
If cell.Value <= cell.Offset(-1).Value Then _
cell.Offset(2) = 1 Else _
cell.Offset(2) = -1
cell.Goalseek Goal:=cell.Offset(-1).Value, ChangingCell:=cell.Offset(1)
```

the last line (your Goalseek) will always be executed regardless of the `If` clause.

Although not a rule, it's usually better to put your code within an `If ... End If` block, so your code would look like this:

```
If cell.Value <= cell.Offset(-1).Value Then
    cell.Offset(2) = 1
Else
    cell.Offset(2) = -1
End If
cell.Goalseek Goal:=cell.Offset(-1).Value, ChangingCell:=cell.Offset(1)
```

This makes it far more obvious what's happening. So the code you need is:

```
If cell.Value > 0 Then
    If cell.Value <= cell.Offset(-1).Value Then
        cell.Offset(2) = 1
    Else
        cell.Offset(2) = -1
    End If
    cell.Goalseek Goal:=cell.Offset(-1).Value, ChangingCell:=cell.Offset(1)
End If
```

Comment: Hi Ambie. Thank you for your reply. I ran the code, and it is still adding 0's in the cells for the column that has 0 in row 62.